# How does Google Static lib for iOS NOT need "other linker flag" (OTHER_LDFLAGS)

Tags: objective-c, ios, static

As we know, a compiled static lib ***.a adds to a project, the project should config the "other linker flag" (OTHER_LDFLAGS) to add value "-ObjC" and "-all_load".

But as I see, the Google libs for iOS do NOT need that, it just simply drag in and use.

Do I miss something?

thanks in advanced.

and sorry for my English epxress.

Travis

Answer (score 2):

```
/*
 * Add this macro before each category implementation, so we don't have to use
 * -all_load or -force_load to load object files from static libraries that only contain
 * categories and no classes.
 * See http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa2006/qa1490.html for more info.
 */

#define TT_FIX_CATEGORY_BUG(name) @interface TT_FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name @end \
                                  @implementation TT_FIX_CATEGORY_BUG_##name @end
```

copied from three20's TTCorePreprocessorMacros.h